# How do I add two numeric arrays in F#

Tags: arrays, f#, operator-overloading

I am totally new to F#. I have searched high and low but I cannot find an example for what I want.

```
let A = [| 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 |];; //maybe delimiter with ;
let B = [| 4.0, 3.5, 2.5, 0.5 |];;

let C = A + B;; //how do I define the addition operator for arrays?
// expect C=[| 5.0, 5.5, 5.5, 4.5 |]
```

I have come close with [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Operator_Overloading) posting, but it is not what I want.

Comment: Those are neither tuples nor arrays, they are in fact the dreaded hybrid: toupees.

Comment: (To be clear, what @Daniel means is that _semicolons_ separate values in array/list literals, whereas _commas_ create tuples.)

Comment: Or to put it in another way: the A and B you created are arrays each containing a single element; that single element is a tuple of 4 numbers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
let inline (++) a b = Array.map2 (+) a b

let A = [| 1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 4.0 |];;
let B = [| 4.0; 3.5; 2.5; 0.5 |];;
let A1 = [| 1; 2; 3; 1 |];;
let B1 = [| 4; 3; 2; 1 |];;

let C = A ++ B
let C1 = A1 ++ B1
```