# Elementwise multiplication of arrays in F#

Tags: arrays, f#, elementwise-operations

Is there a simple way to multiply the items of an array in F#?

So for example of I want to calculate a population mean from samples I would multiply observed values by frequency and then divide by the sample numbers.

```
     let array_1 = [|1;32;9;5;6|];;

     let denominator = Array.sum(array_1);;


     denominator;;

     let array_2 = [|1;2;3;4;5|];;

     let productArray = [| for x in array_1 do
                             for y in array_2 do
                                 yield x*y |];;


     productArray;;

     let numerator = Array.sum(productArray);;

     numerator/denominator;;
```

Unfortunately this is yielding a product array like this:-

```
     val it : int [] =
     [|1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 32; 64; 96; 128; 160; 9; 18; 27; 36; 45; 5; 10; 15; 20; 25;
        6; 12; 18; 24; 30|]
```

Which is the product of everything with everything, whereas I am after the dot product (x.[i]*y.[i] for each i).

Unfortunately adding an i variable and an index to the for loops does not seem to work.

What is the best solution to use here?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421527/how-do-i-add-two-numeric-arrays-in-f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Array.zip array_1 array_2
    |> Array.map (fun (x,y) -> x * y)
```

As the comment points out, you can also use `Array.map2`:

```
Array.map2 (*) array_1 array_2
```

Comment: Brilliant. Hadn't quite got my head around the Array.zip stuff. Will accept when the time limit has passed.

Comment: You could also do `Array.map2 (*) array_1 array_2`.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
Array.map2 (*) xs ys
```

Comment: Hey! John Harrop. Just been reading F# for scientists on the train, looking at the database interops.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
[| for i in 0 .. array_1.Length - 1 ->
    array_1.[i] * array_2.[i] |]
```

should work.